# Get a sub image using opencv Java

Tags: java, image, opencv, mat, submatrix

I have already looked at [how to get sub image by using OpenCV in java api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337813/how-to-get-sub-image-by-using-opencv-in-java-api), but this did not help

I am curious how to create a sub image of a Mat image that I have loaded in from a file. When I run:

```
crop = img.submat(405, 450, 280, 335);
```

I get :

```
  OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m.dims >= 2) in cv::Mat::Mat, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 269
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:269: error: (-215) m.dims >= 2 in function cv::Mat::Mat
]
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_submat_rr(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.submat(Mat.java:2270)
    at Parking.WebCommunications.processImage(WebCommunications.java:54)
    at Parking.WebCommunications.<init>(WebCommunications.java:27)
    at Parking.App.main(App.java:19)
```

I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening. When I run what seems to be a similar piece of code in python on the image it works properly...but I need java to work...

EDIT:

```
    Range xRange = new Range(405, 450);
    Range yRange = new Range(280, 355);
    Mat crop;
    Mat blur = null;

    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java2411");

    //Load image from file
    Mat img = Highgui.imread("/Users/\"User name\"/git/SE300/JavaWorkspace/ParkingLotApp/src/main/resources/bottomOpen.JPG");

    //LOOP:
        //Crop to the Nth spot: cropN = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    System.out.println(img.rows());
    System.out.println(img.cols());

        crop = img.submat(405, 450, 280, 335);
```

Comment: Before the line `crop = img.submat(405, 450, 280, 335);` try to print and debug the `img.rows` and `img.cols` to check if the image was properly loaded.

Comment: @ZdaR I true this and it printed out 0 for both. Is there a specific way to add photos in? I added the rest of the code above:

Comment: Im stupid, not sure where the absolute path was taking it but when I made it "src/main/resources/bottomOpen.JPG" it worked....thanks haha

Answer (score 1):

I manged to do it with some basic classes in Java version of Opencv.

Here is the code for it.

```
// select the region fist        
rectCrop = new Rect(start_x, start_y, width, height);

// generate matrix of the interested region, from original_image
        Mat image_roi = new Mat(original_image, rectCrop);

// code to write the interested image to disk
        Highgui.imwrite("/Users/kapil/Research/test_imgs/out/area_of_intereset.jpg", image_roi);
```